# Finding cyclic vectors for a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_n$ be a non-derogatory matrix (in other words, its minimal and characteristic polynomials coincide). We call  vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is cyclic if $\{A^i \vec{v}\}_{i = 0}^{n - 1}$ be linearly independent. The following theorem ensure that there are such cyclic vectors.

*Theorem:* Let $T$ be a linear operator on vector space $V$ of $n$ dimensional. There exists a cyclic vector for T if and only if minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial are same.(*section 7.1 in Linear algebra by Hoffman-Kunze*)

**My question:** Is there a method for obtaining the cyclic vectors when we have a matrix that it's  minimal and characteristic polynomials coincide or should choose a random vector and test it, is cyclic or not?

*Example:* Consider the following matrix

$$A=\left( \begin {array}{ccc} -3&1&-1\\ -7&5&-1
\\-6&6&-2\end {array} \right)$$
The minimal and characteristic polynomials matrix $A$ is as follows 
$$
{x}^{3}-12\,x-16
$$
If we choose vector $$v= {\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&2&1\end {array} \right]}^T $$
then we have 
$$
F=\{A^i \vec{v}\}_{i = 0}^{3 - 1}= \left( \begin {array}{ccc} 1&-2&4\\ 2&2&20
\\ 1&4&16\end {array} \right)
$$
we can check that $det(F)=0$ and it means  vector $v$ is not cyclic. But If we choose  vector $$v= {\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&3&1\end {array} \right]}^T $$
then we have 
$$
 F=\{A^i \vec{v}\}_{i = 0}^{3 - 1}=\left( \begin {array}{ccc} 1&-1&0\\3&7&32
\\ 1&10&28\end {array} \right)
$$
we can check that $det(F)=-72$ then we conclude that vector $v$ is cyclic.

Comment: It is not *the* vector. It is *a* vector.

Comment: @Jack Thanks, the question is edited by your hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following research paper

[ON THE COMPUTATION OF MINIMAL
POLYNOMIAL, CYCLIC VECTORS AND THE
FROBENIUS FORM](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~augot/LAA_96.pdf) (section 5: Searching for a cyclic vector)

should give an answer to your question.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate for your suggestion.

Comment: Can I ask you to obtain a cyclic vector for my example in the question with using method in lemma $9$ in the section $5$ of article that you introduced. Excuse me for this request. It is a bit difficult to me to understand lemma $9$ in section $5$ for computing a cyclic vector.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Amin235: Having not read the detail of that paper, I think it might be too long to explain it in a comment. May I suggest you to post a follow-up question regarding Lemma 9? (Also you might want explicitly point out in the post where you got stuck in reading it.)

Comment: OK, I try more to understand the method in the section 5, especially lemma 9, if I can not understand the method, I ask it as a question. Thanks for your suggestion.